# How to create a layout file programmatically

Tags: android, dynamic, layout

I was wondering if it were possible to dynamically create an XML layout file to be displayed to the user.  The idea would be to be able to retrieve a layout file from a central server, which could display this dynamic, server driven GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have a problem with the way resource IDs are pre-baked at build time.

Since GUI elements can be instantiated at runtime, you could probably roll your own inflater with an XML parser and a bit of reflection.

Answer (score 2):

XML layout files are packaged as binary and the inflation occurs from binary as well. I don't believe that arbitrary XML can be used for layout.