# XML parser for dynamic layout (dynamically loaded skins)

Tags: android

I want to write an app where (at least for now) the content is always the same but the layout is loaded dynamically at run time based on a user preference. Essentially I want the app to apply a "skin" which may look completely different to other skins.

I found some tutorials using SAXparser:
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser/
http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-how-to-parse-xml-string.html
and can imagine writing something from scratch that recognizes all the standard xml layout tags and then dynamically loads each part of the layout. But that's a lot of work to do from scratch! Surely this functionality is available in android, or surely someone has written some open source code which can be run at the start of your activity's onCreate method, which takes in an xml file and sets your layout?

I found a similar but unsatisfactorily answered question here:
[How to create a layout file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576755/how-to-create-a-layout-file-programmatically)
which makes me think that since setContentView must take an integer resourceID as its argument, the fact that these are pre-baked at compile time might be a problem. (setContentView may also take a View object as its argument, but I don't want a ton of if statements and to pass it each View object one by one, I want some code that inputs an xml file or xml string and sets the content view.)

Maybe I'm way off track. Is there another way to do this? I would think that the ability to have an app with dynamically loaded skins is important.

Thanks!

Comment: Note, I don't want to have the xml file included at compile-time. Instead imagine an xml file on the web, that a compiled application fetches and uses as its skin.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar requirements and tried the same approach - it does not work.

Documentation clearly states this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

**Update:**

Since OP needs to load XML layouts created at runtime:

Possibly this could be done, by creating XML layout files, copying them to dummy project, create .apk and then load apk on to device.

[DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) can be then used to load classes inside apk.

Comment: Hm, you appear to be right (in the link you sent, I am looking at the line beginning "For performance reasons,..."

Comment: Exactly - performance reasons. Layout inflater is used A LOT. Basically every peace of UI is built via LayoutInflater. It seems that they preprocess/precompile all UI XMLs at build time.

Comment: However, can I make a default layout which is just boring listviews and black and white textviews and buttons etc, and then compile like normal. And THEN come back later and apply a skin which uses all the same elements but adds all sorts of crazy things like tiger skin background images? I would think this is totally possible however it relies upon parsing an xml file after compilation, and then a dynamically taking each tag in the xml file and applying it to your layout.. to change color, size, background image, position, etc.I'm hoping someone has some blackbox code I can use that does this

Comment: You can include as many layout XMLs or themes/styles as you want and switch between them at will. You just cant load a new one at runtime. It has to be available at compile time.

Comment: So basically you cant create themes or layouts on server, load them via network and use them.

Comment: Waiiiit. But I could have a default boring black and white layout (let's call it layout.xml) and it compiles perfectly. Then I have a xml file uploaded online somewhere that is the exact same as the layout file but I make ONE change, say, add android:textStyle="bold" inside a textview tag (let's call this file layout2.xml). Then I should be able to write android code that runs the app, downloads the new xml file, parses it, and applies each attribute to each layout element. In doing so it will make that textview to now be bold. Totally possible but tedious no? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Note that of course this is a simple example. In reality MANY tag attributes would be different, so the final skin would look completely different to the starting skin

Comment: I don't know the internals of the LayoutInflater (which is heavily dependent on app context), so I can't say if this would work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looking into it.

However I think you misunderstand, I'm not talking about using LayoutInflater. I'm talking about simply parsing my downloaded layout2.xml file on the fly. Then you have a record of each element (say a textview) and its new attributes (say, bold). Then for each element (which already exists in boring black and white form) you go in and grab that element and set its attribute (e.g. to make it bold), setting attributes one-by-one, dynamically in code. Each attribute will be set with a line of code.

Comment: I'm fuzzy on the details but think it would work, but it is surely tedious! :-)

Comment: Back to your proposal: when I was trying to do it I kept getting AttributeSet not defined exception. This gives a bit more info on what is going on under the hood:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get how you tried to solve it: basically you propose to create a whole new version of LayoutInflater: read all XML nodes/attributes, create UI object hierarchy and apply properties. It's doable but a lot of work.

Comment: This is actually how I solved it, but I really cut down on the number of attributes that can be set. So, I created a few layouts and I only allow customer to change a few things: icons, a few colors, text values, some button placings. It turned out to be okay, because customers do not want too much options. Basically we needed to create a few layouts that fulfill most of customer's needs.

Comment: OK great. Just to clarify, when you say "This is actually how I solved it," you mean, you created a whole new version of LayoutInflater, with reduced number of changeable attributes? Or did you mean something else?

Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Not really - it's much more simple. In the web app user can choose one of fixed templates (e.g. layouts with some elements), then he can change some attributes: label text, some colors, icon images, button titles, button positions, etc.. This is saved as XML. On device there are different Activities, one for each template. Activities are as usual: each has it's own layout XML, which already has all the same UI elements as template. Then I read template XML and apply attributes that user changed. At the end the Activity looks the way user intended.

Comment: Just to add... ive tried inflating a layout residing in another apk and it worked ok. So... its not as stated in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

well, android makes the hard work for you, but no all the the work....

first that all you have to forget about parsing xml layouts... instead you can make skeletons layout, that manages his inner childs position, size, etc... and later inflate that 'skeleton' xml with LayoutInflater and obtain a View instance...

When you have that View instance then you can do what you want with it, applying the users preferences like backgrouds, foregrounds colors, position, sizes, etc...

maybe i dont understand your question but you can get any view inflated from a xml resource at compile-time and later apply other style or set another propertys

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However imagine you don't HAVE the xml layout file at compile time because it will be loaded later on from a website. So you can make a default layout which has boring black and white text and compile it. Then later on, what I want to do is go into a menu or something and click "Use Skin #1" or "Use Skin #2". Then the whole layout should change, all the boring black and white text or basic layout elements that I had should change, *as if I had used that xml file from the very beginning*

Comment: (i.e. as if I had had that xml file as my layout file and THEN compiled it. When in reality I loaded it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is impossible to load the layout & change the skin dynamically according to the doc :

> Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime; it only works with an XmlPullParser returned from a compiled resource (R.something file.)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html