# Dynamically add new UI layout in android app without updating apk file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

How can I add a new UI **layout on the fly** in an already installed app **without updating the apk** on the play store?

The requirement is :
There will be an android app for our customers and a web based backend for the admin.

Admin will be provided with the option to add new UI templates from the admin panel and the same is expected to be changed on the app when the customer navigates to that particular activity.

The idea is, say the admin has changed the template for the product listing activity and after that when the customer visits the product listing activity, we will fetch that new ui template(set by admin) via **HTTP call** from the server and somehow render it on the activity.

How can we achieve this?

PS : We are looking for a completely native solution without any webview.

Comment: "How can we achieve this?" Do you want us to code it for you? I mean you might could *hire* one of us, but that might get pricey. Show us some source code if you'd like the question to be relevant.

Comment: Hey, I am not expecting anyone to write the code but guide me in this direction. The question is so broad that I can not show any source code for it. Hope you understand.

Comment: Well a broad question deserves a broad answer. One could query a webpage for information to inflate a view with. One could also have a custom socket server listening on a server that responds to a request with information (or a serialized view would save some time) to inflate the view with.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to inflate layouot XML which was not available during the build process. The reason is Android does some preprocessing and LayoutInflator relies on preprocessed XML's. Here is a comment from documentation:
[LayoutInflater.inflate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup))

> **Important**   For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime.

And here you can find a good discussion: [XML parser for dynamic layout (dynamically loaded skins)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092829/xml-parser-for-dynamic-layout-dynamically-loaded-skins)

But you still can create your own file format and a parser for it. The complexity of this solution depends on how much customized layouts you need. If it is just reorder or add a few `Views` it is still feasible. But if you need all capabilities that Android layouts provide I don't think you can implement it. In fact you need to implement your own `LayoutInflator` and repeat all that Google did for years...

Comment: Thanks. Your answer seems logical.